# Am I mocking this helper function right in my Django test?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, django-testing

**lib.py**

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
def render_reverse(f, kwargs):
    """
    kwargs is a dictionary, usually of the form {'args': [cbid]}
    """
    return reverse(f, **kwargs)
```

**tests.py**

```
from lib import render_reverse, print_ls

class LibTest(unittest.TestCase):

def test_render_reverse_is_correct(self):
    #with patch('webclient.apps.codebundles.lib.reverse') as mock_reverse:
    with patch('django.core.urlresolvers.reverse') as mock_reverse:
        from lib import render_reverse
        mock_f = MagicMock(name='f', return_value='dummy_views')
        mock_kwargs = MagicMock(name='kwargs',return_value={'args':['123']})
        mock_reverse.return_value = '/natrium/cb/details/123'
        response = render_reverse(mock_f(), mock_kwargs())

        print mock_reverse.mock_calls  # prints []
    print mock_reverse.mock_calls  # prints []
    self.assertTrue('/natrium/cb/details/' in response)
```

But instead, I get

```
  File "/var/lib/graphyte-webclient/graphyte-webenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 296, in reverse
    "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'dummy_readfile' with arguments '('123',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Why is it calling `reverse` instead of my `mock_reverse` (it is looking up my urls.py!!)
You can see `calls` returns an empty list. I even `assert mock_reverse.called` and it returned false.

Maybe I haven't mentioned this, but lib is just a bunch of functions, there is no class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. 1. You need to patch `reverse` from Django. 2. You need to do import inside the context manager, to make `lib` module import mocked `reverse`.

```
from lib import print_ls

class LibTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_render_reverse_is_correct(self):
        with patch('django.core.urlresolvers.reverse') as mock_reverse:
            from lib import render_reverse
            mock_f = MagicMock(name='f', return_value='dummy_view')
            mock_kwargs = MagicMock(name='kwargs',return_value={'args':['123']})
            mock_reverse.return_value = '/natrium/cb/details/123'
            response = render_reverse(mock_f, mock_kwargs)

        self.assertTrue('/natrium/cb/details/' in response)
```

Comment: Thanks. Well, like I said I watched Michael' screencast, the view function calls Poll.objects.get_filter, so he mocked that out (as well as request object). So I thought it was the right thing to do since we don't want to depend on the actual `reverse`.

Comment: @CppLearner I've reread your code and now I don't understand why do you need your `render_reverse` at all. What task does it solve? Why not to use normal `reverse`?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah. I was wrong about making `render_reverse`, but let's think of `render_reverse` as a wrapper that does something before passing to any django built-in functions. I've already patched `reverse`, why is it still using the built-in `reverse`? My poor understanding was that when we patch we are using the mock version, so shouldn't `render_reverse` returns my expected return value?

Comment: @CppLearner I've rewritten the answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping. It is giving me the same error. It seems like `dummy_views` must exist in order to process. The other thing is, when I use a view name that exists, it processed in 0.2 seconds, as opposed to `0.06s` using `mock_reverse` (rather than `render_reverse`. Furthermore, `object.mock_calls` returns empty. It didn't get call at all....

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any keyword arguments (which is a dictionary), and instead passing positional arguments (the tuple).

In addition, your proxy method to reverse only passes the keyword arguments and not the positional arguments.

Finally, you don't have URL that matches the pattern requested - because you didn't pass any keyword arguments, only positional arguments.

Comment: Thanks. Why is it not returning a dictionary? I even tried `mock_f.return_value`, and `mock_f()` . I still end up with the same error.
The expected argument passing is like this: `response = render_reverse('codebundle_homepage',{'args':[cbid]})` and this hard-coded will work.

Comment: BTW In 99% of cases Django doesn't care about the way you pass the arguments. You can `reverse` the same view with `kwargs` and with `args`.